# "usually used to go to" / "usually went to"

Tags: phrase-usage

> Ken **usually used to go to** a disco every week.
>
> Ken **usually went to** a disco every week.

Are both sentences idiomatic? According to my research on the internet, I don't see much uses of "usually used to go to". As I understand it in BrE that phrase isn't used at all. [BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=usually%20used%20to%20go%2Cusually%20went&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3)

Comment: The first example is perfectly "idiomatic", but relatively uncommon compared to the second. Partly that's just because where there's no significant difference in meaning, we naturally tend to choose ***simpler*** verb forms. But there's also a certain element of "tautology" in the first version, since both ***usually*** and ***used to*** carry the same implication of ***was in the habit of***. Forget about BrE / AmE in contexts like this - it's completely irrelevant.

Comment: ...because ***usually*** is a slightly "odd" adverb to collate with ***used to***, [here's a more useful usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=always+used+to+go%2Calways+went&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) with ***always*** instead. As you can see, even without that "tautologous" element, we much prefer the simpler form ***always went*** over ***always used to go***.

Comment: I'm fine with "*usually used to go*", but "*usually used to go ... **every week***" feels odd and either redundant or contradictory. Can't put my finger on which.

Comment: @gotube: I don't think including ***every week*** makes much difference. The fact that there are a dozen or more written instances of ["usually went every morning"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22usually+went+every+morning%22), but only one of ["usually used to go every morning"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22usually+used+to+go+every+morning%22) is just because *usually **went*** is so much more common than *usually **used to go***, whether adverbially qualified for "frequency of occurrence" or not.